# How do I get the total number of rows in a Dojo EnhancedGrid?

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I need to make sure there is at least one row before saving.  I've tried the following but this does not reflect what is in the grid on the screen.

```
var storeUOM = dijit.byId('gridUOM').store;
if (storeUOM._arrayOfAllItems.length == 0) {
    if (errors.length > 1) errors += '\n';
    errors += 'Must setup at least one unit of measure';
}
```

For example the grid may start with 4 rows and the user deletes them all.  This code still returns a length of 4.

Comment: Further clarification...  I initially load the grid using an ItemFileWriteStore.  Then the user has the ability to add or remove from the grid/store.  I found the following link to get the size of the data set but I believe this would get me the original size not the size after adds/deletes.  http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/quickstart/data/usingdatastores/faq#question-6-how-do-i-get-a-count-of-all-items-in-a-datastore

Answer (score 1):

Actually the following code from that link works perfectly!  I does not reload the store from the URL it just returns the size of the current store.

```
var storeUOM = dijit.byId('gridUOM').store;
function size(size, request) {
   if (size == 0) {
      if (errors.length > 1) errors += '\n';
      errors += 'Must setup at least one unit of measure';
   }
}
storeUOM.fetch({query: {}, onBegin: size, start: 0, count: 0});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var totalRows = dijit.byId('gridUOM').rowCount ;
```